# Load images by default for HTML Emails in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

It seems that each time I go to open an HTML message in Evolution I have to goto View -> Load Images. Is there a way to change this so Images will be automatically downloaded each time I receive an HTML message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Evolution, open `Edit > Preferences > Mail Preferences > HTML Messages`. You should see an option for "Loading Images." Select "Always load images from internet."

[image: evo-prefs]